# SQLException (UnsupportedOperationException) while trying to instantiate Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

For my job, I have to use **Hibernate** for the first time on a project. Actually, everything was set up by someone else and now I have to expand the "queries" a bit.
We have a **Tomcat v7.0** server running in **Eclipse**, the **Quartz** framework is used to schedule a query every 5 minutes. This query then is executed/handled by Hibernate. I think I understand most of it, but as I said: I'm a newbie here, so this question migh be really stupid, but I was not able to find an answer using Google/StackOverflow, so here goes.

Since I modified some things in the querying config of hibernate, I get `null` results all the time. After some struggling, I have logging up and running. This is the (I think) **relevant part of the log** I get when starting the Tomcat server:

```
30-apr-2012 11:02:32 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
WARNING: Could not obtain connection metadata
java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:62)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.handleThrowable(NewPooledConnection.java:369)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyDatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion(NewProxyDatabaseMetaData.java:3692)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:753)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:691)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:268)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:268)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:170)
    at com.mh2o.dbase.manager.HibernateDaoManager.getInstance(HibernateDaoManager.java:17)
    at com.mh2o.dbase.wbuserlist.WelcomeBoardMgr.<init>(WelcomeBoardMgr.java:11)
    at com.mh2o.application.cache.welcomeboard.WelcomeCache.synchronize(WelcomeCache.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:283)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:272)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyDatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion(NewProxyDatabaseMetaData.java:3678)
    ... 53 more
30-apr-2012 11:02:32 org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory buildTransactionFactory
```

So, there appears to be an error in the SQL. Now, I have added some files, so I guess that is where the error arises. The database contains a table that can be joined to the tables that were already queried, which is what I did:

**employeeavailablehours.hbm.xml** (describe table in database):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.mh2o.application.vo.planningview" schema="N_C">
 <class name="EmployeeAvailableHours" table="WerknemersBeschikbareUr">
    <id column="ID" name="id" type="string">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property column="InitialenWerknemer"  name="initial" generated="never" lazy="false" not-null="true" type="string"/>
    <property column="Vanaf"  name="from" generated="never" lazy="false" not-null="true" type="string"/>
    <property column="Tot"  name="to" generated="never" lazy="false" not-null="true" type="string"/>
    <property column="Volgnummer"  name="indexnumber" generated="never" lazy="false" not-null="true" type="string"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**employeeinfo.hbm.xml** (created by someone else already, modified by me to include a reference to above table):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.mh2o.application.vo.planningview" schema="N_C">
 <class name="EmployeeInfo" table="WerknemersInfo">
    <id column="ID" name="id" type="string">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property column="Naam"  name="name" generated="never" lazy="false" not-null="true" type="string"/>
    <property column="InitialenWerknemer"  name="initial" generated="never" lazy="false" not-null="true" type="string"/>
    <set name="employeeavailablehours" table="WerknemersBeschikbareUr" inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="InitialenWerknemer" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="EmployeeAvailableHours"  />
    </set>
  </class>


</hibernate-mapping>
```

Of course, I have added the new table, employeeavailablehours, in `context.xml` and created classes to represent the data from the new table as named in the xml file. Furthermore, I have edited the class that represented the existing table to also hold a reference to the table I added. I think this is not where the error arises, looking at the exception, which is why I do not include the Java source of those classes here. If needed, I will of course.

If you guys need more information, please ask and I'll edit my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using jdbc-odbc bridge to connect using hibernate?? check if this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289121/using-hibernate-via-an-odbc-connection

Comment: As far as I know, we do not use ODBC. I should note that if I remove my modifications to the XML files, the query just works, so I think it is not a connection problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I was doing something completely wrong: the key I was using as a foreign key could not be used as a foreign key at all. Changing the complete setup of where to join the one table with the other solved the issue.